# I can't add a Trigger using 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, triggers

So I have table1, table2, table3 ...

```
table 1 has G_Id, G_y
table 2 has S_ID, G_ID(FK), S_Date
Table 3 has N_ID, S_ID(FK), N_Date
```

I wanted to create the trigger after an update on Table 3
for any new N_date (table3) update Table 1 G_y(not a date) by calculating (N_date - S_date) * 11

I can't figure it out.

Comment: anybody figure it out?

Comment: Can you explain what table you want to update with the trigger again. You're sentence/explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: This does not seem like a very difficult question what have you tried. What SQL attempts have you written. Did you research ORACLE After Triggers at all?

Comment: I want to update table 1 field G_y  when Table 3 is updated. and the calculation is (the newly update N_date - S_Date) * 11 then added to G_Y in table 1. I don't know if that made sense

Comment: Yes I researched and tried to create the trigger but it's not working.I don't have to much experience with triggers.

Comment: Can you post in your question what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using MySQL you can do it like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER n_date_insert_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON table3
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN
(
  SELECT g_id, DATEDIFF(NEW.n_date, s_date) * 11 g_y
    FROM table2 t2 
   WHERE s_id = NEW.s_id
) q ON t1.g_id = q.g_id
   SET t1.g_y = q.g_y;

CREATE TRIGGER n_date_update_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE ON table3
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN
(
  SELECT g_id, DATEDIFF(NEW.n_date, s_date) * 11 g_y
    FROM table2 t2 
   WHERE s_id = NEW.s_id
) q ON t1.g_id = q.g_id
   SET t1.g_y = q.g_y;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/440b0/1)** demo